# SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.:

Tags: apex, custom-object, email-template, lookup, apex-email-service

> Error: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, WhatId is not available for sending emails to UserIds.

I want to send email through the snippet in below.

```
List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mailList = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTemplateId('00XJ0000000mq21MAA');//Email Template is
mail.setTargetObjectId('005J00000076xlj');//Contact,lead or userid to be specified.
mail.setWhatId('a03J000001Dc6vPIAR');//Custom object id
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mailList.add(mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
```

> It is throwing above exception when I pass userId inside setTargetObjectId.

```
mail.setTargetObjectId('005J00000076xlj');
```

It is working fine when I pass contactId or leadId.

Please help me to send email to UserId

Answer (score 0):

`setWhatId` is only available when in `setTargetObjectId` we specify Lead or contact Record ID.

So you are getting the expected behavior.

There is one workaround which I use. In `setTargetObjectId` give any dummy contact ID. `SetToaddress` method pass the UserId. And then set the `setTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient(false)` to false. So your contact won't receive the email.

Comment: no i still get the SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Comment: @compskiI suggest you to create a new question and add details there.

Comment: sure check this out https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/287192/38191